# Adding zero values to an array

Tags: php, sql, flot

I am doing the following queries on a database that holds various customers orders.

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(orderDateTime) Date, COUNT(clientID) totalCount FROM orders WHERE YEARWEEK(orderDateTime,1) = YEARWEEK(NOW(),1) GROUP BY DATE(orderDateTime)

SELECT WEEKDAY(orderDateTime) Date, COUNT(clientID) totalCount FROM orders WHERE YEARWEEK(orderDateTime,1) = YEARWEEK(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK,1) GROUP BY DATE(orderDateTime)

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(orderDateTime, '%Y') as 'year', DATE_FORMAT(orderDateTime, '%m') as 'month', COUNT(clientID) as 'total' FROM orders GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(orderDateTime, '%Y%m')
```

I am them building these into an array with the month/ day numbers against the counted value:

[[0, 1], [1,4]...]

I am using Flot to graph these but what is happening is that any days or months that there are no orders it has no values (Obviously) so what you get is something like this:

[[0, 1], [1,4], [6,12]] which makes the graph plot wrong.

What trying to work out is how to pad it so it looks like:

[[0, 1], [1,4], [2,0], [3,0], [4,0], [5,0], [6,12]] <-- For the week days and,

[[1, 1], [2,4], [3,0], [4,0], [5,0], [6,0], [7,12], [8,0], [9,12], [10,0], [11,0], [12,0]] <-- for each month.

Im using PHP as the main grunt. Any pointers would be appreciated and sorry if I'm not that clear. Ask if you need any clarification.

PHP:

```
$thisWeekA = array();

$thisWeekQ = $database->query("SELECT WEEKDAY(orderDateTime) Date, COUNT(clientID) totalCount FROM orders WHERE YEARWEEK(orderDateTime,1) = YEARWEEK(NOW(),1) GROUP BY DATE(orderDateTime)")->fetchAll();

foreach($thisWeekQ as $thisweek){
    $thisWeekA[] = array( $thisweek['Date'], $thisweek['totalCount'] );
}

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Date"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["totalCount"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Date"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [0]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["totalCount"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

Comment: So you need your php input data to flot graph to be processed. For more understanding can you share the php code you used to prepare the graph onput data

Comment: please update this in your question

Comment: on a weekly graph [0 (sunday), 12(count of orders)] am i right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was tagged javascript when I wrote my now deleted answer.

Comment: If there was a way of doing it JS then I'm all ears. :)

Comment: I'll undelete my "answer".  If it does not help then let me know and I'll re-delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out a way of doing this. Thanks for pointing me in the direction of the For loop!

This is what I have came up with and works!

```
function arrayhunt($products, $field, $value){

   foreach($products as $key => $product){

        if ($product[$field] == $value){
            return $key;
        }
   }
   return false;
}


    $i = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {

        $keys = arrayhunt($thisWeekQ,"Date",$i);

        if($keys !== FALSE){
            $thisWeekA[] = array($thisWeekQ[$keys]['Date'], $thisWeekQ[$keys]['totalCount']);
        } else {
            $thisWeekA[] = array($i, 0);
        }

        $keys = "";
    }
```

Hopefully someone finds this useful later.

Answer (score 1):

for weekly data use for loop in your php update it as,
Logic only 7 days in a week of instead of using foreach from the result data we can use the for loop for seven days

i.e., similarly use for years also

```
$thisWeekA = array();    
$thisWeekQ = $database->query("SELECT WEEKDAY(orderDateTime) Date, COUNT(clientID) totalCount FROM orders WHERE YEARWEEK(orderDateTime,1) = YEARWEEK(NOW(),1) GROUP BY DATE(orderDateTime)")->fetchAll();

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {
        if ($thisWeekQ[$i]['Date'] == $i) {
            $thisWeekA[$i][] = array($thisWeekQ[$i]['Date'], $thisWeekQ[$i]['totalCount']);
        } else {
            $thisWeekA[$i][] = array($i, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have added what the output of the query looks like.

Comment: Sorry, my comment wasn't that clear! Had a fiddle about due to it looking at the array number it means it will never match with an order count. All my numbers come out as 0.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to think about building your arrays more like this:

```
var dow = [];
dow[0] = 1;
dow[1] = 4;
dow[6] = 12;
```

At this point you can populate your array for your chart

```
var chartData = [];
for (var i=0; i<7; i++){
    chartData[i] = [i, (dow[i] === undefined ? 0 : dow[i])];
}
```